# Integrating google analytics using android studio, not work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

I integrated google analytics using "android studio -> file -> project structure -> analytics", it have added these files :

1- my full androidmanifest http://pastebin.com/Kw83uDTi

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

3- res.xml/app_tracker.xml with these data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-72582079-3</string>

    <!--
      See Project Structure -> Analytics -> Google Analytics -> Learn More
      to learn more about configuring this file.
    -->
</resources>
```

3- file AnalyticsTrackers.java
http://pastebin.com/1TqUYKpW

But I tested the app and it doesn't look that google analytics working, I must do something else? someone have tested this option in android studio?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking at Real Time?

Comment: yes at real time Eugene

Comment: Okay.  How do you know it is not working? Also post code how you are implementing your tracking.

Comment: I will post a simple example of how the manifest is supposed to be setup.

Comment: I looked at real time, and stats of today, but all values are 0.  what you mean with implementing? android studio just created some files as explained in first post, example : "3- file AnalyticsTrackers.java http://pastebin.com/1TqUYKpW" and it added some lines to androidmanfiest and gradle dependency

Comment: ok, the <meta-data is supposed to be within < / application >

Comment: Here is my androidmanifest : http://pastebin.com/Kw83uDTi

Comment: Are you using the correct ga_trackingId?